# Filtering by user on the server-side with WCF Data Services

Tags: wcf, wcf-security, wcf-data-services

I'm trying to create an WCF Data Services service which allows documents to be downloaded from a server, to client applications running .NET 4.0.

The documents should only be downloadable by the user which owns them. Users can be authenticated on the server with a username and password. And I've found a way of sending the user credentials from the client to the server (`DataServiceContext.Credentials`).

The area that I'm struggling with is being able to restrict the documents returned by the service to just the subset owned by the user. I can check that the username and password is valid easily enough but I'm not sure how I should then use that to filter the results.

I don't have a complex model on the server, just a list of documents and associated user accounts. Some documents may be shared between a number of users.

Am I trying to do something which WCF Data Services isn't really designed for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I've found a good solution - **query interceptors**:

[How to: Intercept Data Service Messages (WCF Data Services)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/site/dd744837)